# Objective-C: Keep updating locations while I navigate to other view

Tags: ios, navigation, cllocationmanager

this is my first question as I'm quite newbie in iOS programming.

I'm developing an app in which I have to save the route of a city drive.
I have DetailsView where I update user's locations like a city run. That view also has a "back" button that jumps to PreviousView. 
PreviousView has a button to move again to the current city run.

My question is, can I keep updating locations while user moves between both views? 
I looking for any solution that allow DetailsView work as if it was in Background mode.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: please add your code of location update to AppDelegate  and you can update and fetch location from appDelegate  its .. very Simple..

Comment: In viewDidAppear of DetailsView you can update the location right?

Comment: `CLLocationManager` will update your respective location, you don't need to worry about. Make sure you have set up all things properly.

Comment: Thanks everyone, Mitul solution made the trick for now.
Thank you!